# mavenized java webapp and javascript dependency management

Tags: javascript, eclipse, maven

I have a java webapp project under eclipse that is using maven for dependency management. 
This webapp also depends on many javascript libraries for the front-end, either provided by external "vendors" such as jquery or bootstrap, or developped "internally" by myself.

What I want to do is manage the javascript dependencies just as I would with  java dependecies, inside my POM.xml.

Now, for external dependencies I would like them to be automatically downloaded from a repository ( either hosted by me or external) - this is what Webjars could provide I believe.

For my "internal" javascript libraries I would like to create them as separate eclipse projects, in my eclipse workspace, that would be referenced inside my webapp's POM the same way I would do with a secondary java project residing in my eclipse workspace.

I also want the referenced js dependencies to be properly placed under my /src/main/webapp/js/ folder when the webapp is deployed.

Finally, when modifying something in one of my "internal" javascript libraries, I would like the changes to be automatically deployed to the webapp, as if it was a regular java sub-project referenced in the main webapp project. I specially want the changes to be redeployed to the webapp if it is running / being debugged, under eclipse.

I have heard of Javascript maven tools : http://javascript-maven.softec.lu/
or http://mojo.codehaus.org/javascript-maven-tools/javascript-maven-plugin/
but thes plugins dont seem to be maintained anymore, are lightly documented, and I failed achieving the above requirements with them (probably because of the lack of concrete examples).

Now I know I'm asking for alot but I dont mind trying different approaches, and fooling around with different tools.

Any help, thoughts, insights etc ...  appreciated

Thanks

Comment: not sure if there is something out there which manages javascript version for dependency management

Comment: I think [require.js](http://requirejs.org) is what you're looking for... I've never used it, but I believe it is used for handling which JS files load on which pages (highly configurable), so it's probably something you may want to look into. I don't have any idea if you can integrate it with Maven though...